# cannot reach a webcam behind two routers

Tags: ip, port, webcam, forwarding

I am using internet over cable and this is connected via a Vodafone cable router. Attached to a lan port of that Vodafone router is my ASUS Router, which provides WLAN in another floor of my house. Attached to the ASUS Router via WLAN is a WebCam.

If I access a port (lets say 8010) on my IP this should allow me to access the web cam.

```
           IP 45.12.1.4                   (LAN) IP 192.168.0.x           (WLAN) IP 192.168.1.y
   Internet ------------> Vodafone Router -------------------> ASUS Router ----------------> WebCam
```

(The IP address above is dummy.)

If I access http://45.12.1.4:8010 I want to access the WebCam.

For that I have used port forwarding on the Vodafone Router:

```
LAN-IP-Adresse  Protokoll   LAN Port (Bereich)  WAN Port (Bereich)  
 192.168.0.x     TCP           8010               8010
```

Then I have configured the ASUS Router:

```
Servicename Source Target   Portbereich Lokale IP   Lokaler Port    Protokoll
IP-Camera                   8010        192.168.1.y   8010           TCP
```

When I try to access the camera via the IP address and port number, I get a time out and the server cannot be reached.
How can I achieve this double forwarding?